# How can I compare dates with 3 x primitive int dd mm yyyy?

Tags: java, date, integer

I have a Java assignment yet one condition is I have to use 3 int dd mm yyyy to compare dates with another 3 int ddd mmm yyyy.
I have to check whether someone's birthday is earlier than 15 Oct 1950, but if his BD is later, need to check whether if it is between 15 Oct 1950 and 16 Oct 1975. If yes continue with main conditions and stuff and if no, exit. And if his BD is older, proceed with main conditions.
I can't use method or array, can't call class, only comparing primitive Int...

```
int bddd = kb.nextInt(); 
int bdmm = kb.nextInt(); 
int bdyyyy = kb.nextInt();

//how do I check dates with int?? 
if(bdyyyy<=1975 && bdmm<=10 && bddd<=15) {
  int ddd = kb.nextInt(); 
  int mmm = kb.nextInt(); 
  int yyy = kb.nextInt();

  if(yyy>1950||(yyy>=1950 && mmm<=10 && ddd<=16)){
        // do another date check,
           if(//date check true) {
               //  go back to main stuff
           else
              System.out.println //end my misery


// main stuffs

                           
}
```

Comment: The normal solution would be to use the standard `LocalDate` class. Is there anything preventing you from doing so? Asking because it may sound like homework, and homework assignments sometimes have funny unnatural restrictions.

Comment: At least, one would normally write a method that compares two dates. Why can't you use methods?

Comment: It is rather unclear what you have to do in each case. There are three possible cases: before 1950, between 1950 and 1975, and after 1975.

Comment: Can you use math? Like summing and multiplying.

Comment: @OleVV "Funny unnatural restrictions" LOL

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you the code for your first IF. You should do something similar in the second one.

If you can use math, it becomes lot easier:

```
if (bdyyyy * 10000 + bdmm * 100 + bddd < 19751015) {
```

But if you can't do that, you have to:

```
if (
    (bdyyyy < 1975) ||
    (bdyyyy == 1975 && bdmm < 10) ||
    (bdyyyy == 1975 && bdmm == 10 && bddd < 15)
   ) {
```

That could also be simplified a bit,

```
if (
    (bdyyyy < 1975) ||
    (bdyyyy == 1975 && (
         bdmm < 10 ||
         (bdmm == 10 && bddd < 15)
    )
   ) {
```

Comment: Easier? Maybe easier to write, not easier to read, which is what counts in programming. Also the OP would have learned more from writing the concrete code himself.

Comment: Thanks Rafael! The maths is awesome! i used it to simplify the comparisons, hopefully that i dont get penalised.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it, though probably not what your assignment expects:

```
int compare = Arrays.compare(new int[] {bdyyyy, bdmm, bddd}, new int[] {1950, 10, 15});
if (compare > 0) {
    // It's after that date.
    compare = Arrays.compare(new int[] {bdyyyy, bdmm, bddd}, new int[] {1975, 10, 15});
    if (compare < 0) {
        // It's before this date.
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks dodgy! I cant use array, I can only if, else if, switch, no methods, no arrays no classes. Very restrictive to do the assignment.